# How to define empty multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use multidimensional array model in my vuejs project

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/30596/) of my code:

I define an array in my vuejs data

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    arr: [[1,2],[3,4]]
  }
})
```

and use:

```
<p v-if="arr[3][0]">{{ arr[3][0] }} //Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"
</p>
```

but I have error when I call not defined index

> Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   '1' of undefined"

I use `v-if` to skip undefined index but it doesn't work [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/30596/)

How can I solve this problem and skip not defined index?

**UPDATE:**

`v-if` not work correctly because of using it in `<br>` tag I changed `<br>` to `<span>` and problem solved

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, try `arr[1][0]`

Comment: @taylorc93 I know that , I want to skip error for not defined index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test whether the top-level array element exists before testing whether the second-level array element exists.

```
<p v-if="arr[2] && arr[2][0]">
```

Comment: I did check it on the fiddle, and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/30599/

Comment: my problem was because of using if condition in br tag I replaced with span and solved